# How to put Lumen API to production? What host?

Tags: php, lumen, production

I've made an API in PHP Lumen, and I try to put it in production.
That's the first time that I do so, so I'm kinda lost ^^'

I usually launch the server using

```
php -S localhost:3000 -t public
```

Could you explain how I can put my project in production?

Sorry, I've looked tons of articles but can't wrap my head around this!

Thx for the help =)

Comment: on which system you are going to deploy the application ? on c-panel or some cloud?

Comment: you don't need to run the command on the server !

Comment: Use pm2 service to start the app and add the proxy pass in vhost file

Answer (score 0):

Steps to upload lumen project in server.

1. Upload your project into server root directory.
2. Move Public folder to root directory which is present in your project folder.
3. Update public/index.php file this line

   $app = require **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

   to

   $app = require **DIR**.'/../your-project-folder-name/bootstrap/app.php';
4. access your project [www.example.com/public/](http://www.example.com/public/)
5. You can also change public folder name.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Here is the solution to your problem.

1. Create the Server block for your project.
   I'm using nginx

```
server {
        server_name <<domin name>>;
        root /srv/<<project name>>/public;
        index index.php index.html;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
        location ~ \.php {
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED 
                $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
                $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
        
        location ~* \.(css|less|js|jpg|png|gif)$ {
                add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
                add_header Pragma "no-cache";
                expires 0;
        }
}
```